# Angular4, forms set to valid when initializing

Tags: angular

I have the following component:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myForm.valueChanges
        .subscribe(() => {
          if(this.myForm.valid) {
            doSomethingWithTheFormData()
          }
        })
  }
```

and in my template:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

The only worry is that by default myForm.valid is `true`, even though I have some `required` fields unset. It thus fails in my `doSomethingWithTheFormData()`since some of them are missing.
It's like if the initialization of the form wasn't fully done (despite being in `ngAfterViewInit()`).

I managed to work around the issue by adding a `this.myForm.dirty` in my condition but I feel like this isn't the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a FormGroup from the @angular/forms module?

```
this.eventForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  startTime: ['', Validators.required],
  endTime: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Then in your template

```
<form class="event-publisher__form" [formGroup]="eventForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate> 
   enter code here
</form>
```

I should note that this is using the ReactiveFormsModule. Import this module in your feature module then inject a FormBuilder to your component.

Comment: Well, just a cauz I want to use template-driven form not model-driven form here

Comment: Template-driven forms delegate creation of their form controls to directives. These take more than one cycle to build the entire tree, thus you have to wait before manipulating any of these controls. Using ngAfterViewInit you'll having to use a setTimeout before you can validate a control or set a value.